# Passing default arguments along function handles in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Say that I have the following function

```
function y = f(x,a)
    if nargin < 2
        a = 2;
    end
    y = x.^2 - a;
end
```

I have another function which finds the root through Newton's method. Say that this is how I call upon the method :

```
newton(@f,@df,x0)
```

If I run the newton function with the supplied arguments, then it will only run for the default value of a = 2.

I was wondering if it is possible to some how specify a default parameter for a function when sending it through a function handle. Like this for instance

```
newton(@f(a),@df,x0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean [this `newton`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28227-newton-s-method/content/newton.m), then it expects a univariate function. You can still use your bivariate function `f`, but you have to be tricky: you need to define a new, anonymous function, and use your variable `a` as parameter to that:

```
a = 3; %or any other specific value, have to be set before calling newton
newton(@(x) f(x,a),@df,x0)
```

If you find that more transparent, you can also do it in a separate step:

```
f_uni = @(x) f(x,a); %defines f_uni(x), "a" is a parameter to it
newton(f_uni,@df,x0);
```

Note that in this case `f_uni` is already a function handle, so you don't have to (and mustn't) put a `@` before it.

Comment: I should have specified clearly that the Newton implementation is my own. But I tried your suggestion, and that was exactly what I wanted!